# Django Python manage.py migrate doesnt work

Tags: python, django, installation

I'm having trouble with installing django. This is what I got. I only installed python and django. didnt change any files, there is an error that come out

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat>manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\_
_init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\managem
ent\commands\migrate.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migration
s\autodetector.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migration
s\questioner.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migration
s\loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migration
s\recorder.py", line 12, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migration
s\recorder.py", line 26, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migration
s\recorder.py", line 27, in Migration
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fi
elds\__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init_
_.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init_
_.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init_
_.py", line 116, in __init__
    setattr(self, setting, setting_value)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\smat\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init_
_.py", line 85, in __setattr__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("If set, %s must end with a slash" % name)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: If set, STATIC_URL must end with a
slash
```

How do I deal with it?? please help) Cant post my question, because it asks for more information, but to me there is no additional info

Answer (score 1):

The error says your `STATIC_URL` value doesn't end with a slash. Checking your settings.py file and make sure it has a slash at the end of the value - a forward slash.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: It does end with a slash actually.

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts of your settings file in the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

This is exact copy of `static` in `settings.py`